# NameNotFoundException when I change app icon and name with activity-alias

Tags: android, kotlin

I try to change my app icon and name in runtime.

```
val pm = activity.packageManager
val packageName = BuildConfig.APPLICATION_ID

activity.packageManager.setComponentEnabledSetting(
    ComponentName(packageName, packageName + activeName),
    PackageManager.COMPONENT_ENABLED_STATE_ENABLED,
    PackageManager.DONT_KILL_APP)

for (i in disableNames.indices) {
try {
    activity.packageManager.setComponentEnabledSetting(
        ComponentName(packageName, disableNames[i]),
        PackageManager.COMPONENT_ENABLED_STATE_DISABLED,
        PackageManager.DONT_KILL_APP)
     } catch (e: Exception) {
         e.printStackTrace()
     }
}
```

App icon and name change right, but if after it I try to change app theme I have got a crash

```
Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.app.test.debug/com.app.test.presentation.ui.main.activity.MainActivity}: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: android.content.pm.PackageManager$NameNotFoundException: ComponentInfo{com.app.test.debug/com.app.test.presentation.ui.main.activity.MainActivity-default}
```

What am I doing wrong?

---

```
    <activity-alias
        android:exported="true"
        android:label="Default"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_red"
        android:name=".presentation.ui.main.activity.MainActivity-default"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:targetActivity="com.app.test.presentation.ui.main.activity.MainActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity-alias>

    <activity-alias
        android:exported="true"
        android:label="Second alias"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_green"
        android:name=".presentation.ui.main.activity.MainActivity-settings"
        android:enabled="false"
        android:targetActivity="com.app.test.presentation.ui.main.activity.MainActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity-alias>
```

This is how my activity-alias look like

The problem in this part on code

```
   activity.packageManager.setComponentEnabledSetting(
                ComponentName(BuildConfig.APPLICATION_ID, "com.app.test.presentation.ui.main.activity.MainActivity-default"),
                PackageManager.COMPONENT_ENABLED_STATE_DISABLED, PackageManager.DONT_KILL_APP)
```

When I remove this part it helps. But now I got two icons old and new one. The old icon does not remove.

The logic:
1) Enable activity-alias. 
2) Disable old activity-alias
3) Recreate activity
4) Crash java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: android.content.pm.PackageManager$NameNotFoundException: ComponentInfo{com.app.test.debug/com.app.test.presentation.ui.main.activity.MainActivity-default}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i think you don't use manifest config for this action.

in the manifest must set the activity-alias

like :

```
<activity-alias android:enabled=["true"|"false"]
 android:exported=["true"|"false"]
 android:icon="drawable"
 android:label="string resource"
 android:name="string resource"
 android:permission="string resource"
 android:targetActivity="string resource">

</activity-alias>
```

i found [this link](https://shabbirdhangot.wordpress.com/2016/04/01/change-application-name-and-launcher-icon-runtime/)

and this [github example](https://github.com/shabbir-dhangot/Application-Launcher-Icon-And-Name-Changer)

attention :

it's only work in java 
if you want it you con not use kotlin because in kotlin ComponentName() method check the existing of the input files

use java code and

Comment: I added below how my activity-alias look like

Comment: Thx mate, I will try

Comment: complete you question to get answer

Comment: Thx mate. It is a good sample. I made a test project on kotlin and it work fine. But in my project I still get the error

Answer (score 0):

You are not doing anything wrong
I had the same problem.
Managed to debug only after creating completly new activity with the same code only to get again `Crash java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: android.content.pm.PackageManager$NameNotFoundException:`

It tells you that it doesn't find the activity - because you changed the name of the activity - so - it cannot be found, and cannot install and replace the apk.
when you remove the "COMPONENT_ENABLED_STATE_DISABLED" - you made second crime - you left 2 activities running. while Only one is allowed at the same time.

to fix it , make sure you return to the default activity-alias otherwise you cannot debug this activity anymore. uninstall the app and probably create new activity.
maybe - I didn't try it - try changing the order of the activity-alias so the one chosen currently will be the first one.